# Unable to change kivy icon

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change icon from kivy default one to some ico/png file that i provide

But it seems to be not working

I get this
[image]

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder 

KV="""

Button:
    text:""

"""

class Main(MDApp):
    def build (self):
        self.icon="image.png"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        
Main().run()
```

Update:
Fixed the problem by changing the png,
But it still shows kivy logo for the loading screen ,is there any fix for this.???

Comment: icon in the same directory as the script?

Comment: Actually i fixed it by converting the image to png (png to png) , maybe something was wrong the png i used earlier

Comment: But it still shows the kivy logo for the loading screen, how could i fix that.??

Comment: On android or where?

Comment: Windows operating system

Comment: `from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','window_icon','path/to/icon.ico')`